# When touchesMoved() is called the view lags for a second

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

When I first the touches moved in the code below is called I get a long lag which is not good for the user experience.

```
override public  func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if gameOverTransitoning {
            return
        }

        if gameState == .waiting || gameState == .gameOver {
            return
        }

        var i = 0
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {

            //allow 2 touches to move, can make the ship move faster
           if i >= 2 {
                break
            }

            let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
            let previous = touch.previousLocation(in: self)
            let amountDraggedX = pointOfTouch.x - previous.x
            let amountDraggedY = pointOfTouch.y - previous.y

            var x = player.position.x + amountDraggedX
            x = max(player.size.width / 2, x)
            x = min(self.size.width - player.size.width / 2, x)

            var y = player.position.y
            if allowVerticalMove {
                y += amountDraggedY
                y = max(self.size.height * playerMinY, y)
                y = min(self.size.height * playerMaxY, y)
                if i == 0 {
                    let deltaY = y - player.position.y
                    player.accelerate(accelerate: deltaY)
                }
            }

            player.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

            i += 1

        }

    }

}
```

This is the code below. The touches moved function is the touches moved function in SpriteKit

Comment: As Jacek Grygiel said we do not know how heavy is the stuff you are doing in player.accelerate or other layer methods called above. Besides as far as I remember touchesMoved is normally called 60 times per second. Are you sure you need to execute above code so many times?

Comment: what diagnostics have you put in so far e.g. some `print` statements to show where in your code you are?

Comment: @LeszekSzary No touchesMoved is called only when touches moved... and is unrelated to frame rating only to user interaction

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès yes that is correct, what I meant is that if he is constantly moving the finger on the screen then touchesMoved will be called 60 times per second (afaik this is how fast it catches touch events).

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't know what you are doing with:

```
   player.accelerate(accelerate: deltaY)
```

Have you tried to run this code on the different thread ? Is it running on the main thread currently? if yes than that could be a reason.